# Why can't I install Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects?

Tags: visual-studio, package

So i'm trying to install this package to create Setup.exe for my project, but it goes with error:
[image]

```
Install log:
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - -------------------------------------------
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - 16.9.2017
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - -------------------------------------------
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - Command line parameters:
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Community,/skuVersion:16.9.31229.75,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019,/culture:ru-RU,/noep,C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXabkei5yl.vsix
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - -------------------------------------------
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
12.06.2021 15:47:52 - -------------------------------------------
12.06.2021 15:47:53 - System.IO.FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Имя файла: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   в VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.AddInstalledIsolatedShells(Version vsVersion, IntPtr userToken)
   в VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.InitializeSupportedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   в VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.InitializeSupportedSKUs(ICommandLineData cmdLineData, IntPtr duplicatedUserToken)
   в VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   в VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Edit: edited and added error window in english so it'll be more understandable

Comment: Maybe you need to install a different .Net Framework runtime Version first (which is not a good sign for the quality of that installer)

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone'll encounter this problem, i repaired Visual Studio in Visual Studio installer and it actually helped!